# Persistently disable Intel Turbo Boost

Tags: drivers, configuration, cpu, power-management, cpu-frequency

Through the magic of piezoelectric phenomena, I experience "coil whine" when moving the mouse.

Turns out said coil is energized by the CPU, and that the Intel driver enabling Turbo Boost makes it process my mouse movements **extremely quickly**, resulting in audible power consumption spikes.

When I disable it with the following command, I get back my sanity:

`echo "1" | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo`

But unfortunately, it only lasts until the next reboot.

Is there a way to persistently disable Turbo Boost? Perhaps via some incantation involving `x86_energy_perf_policy` or `cpuinfo`?

In case it's relevant, my particular CPU model is i9-10900.

Comment: If running Debian, you can try the `sysfsutils` package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this command to `rc.local` or create a systemd unit - whatever you like. Instead of disabling Turbo you might want to limit the maximum operating frequency of your CPU. There's a gulf between base and turbo frequencies, so disabling Turbo feels like an overkill. I have a [script](https://github.com/birdie-github/useful-scripts/blob/master/cpumode) for that as well. With the intel-pstate driver you're free to set any maximum CPU operating frequency.

Comment: I overprovisioned my CPU, and I don't really need Turbo. If there were a way for it not to kick in so quickly (avoiding audible frequencies or intensities), maybe I'd use it. But ever since I replaced my power supply with a silent one, I can hear it. ~^\_/^~ Before accepting your answer, I will wait for some more, in case there is no need to set up a startup command. Thanks!